# find max of some matrix elements in C

Tags: c, matrix

so I got a task at my Uni a week ago: 
There is n*n matrix given which is a square matrix, but I have to find max of these elements on the picture, question is how to do it ?[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Are you actually asking how to find the "max element" of a screenshot of a browser window displaying a PDF, in which nothing resembles an element? If you're asking about the shaded triangle, you need whatever numeric values created it in the first place. There's no obvious way to assign numeric values to anything shown in that picture though.

Comment: the elements are given by teacher, I need to make a program that finds the max element of that triangle range in the screenshot.

Comment: So you first need to figure out where your matrix comes from and how it's represented. Are you putting it into your program as a constant 2 dimensional array? Then you need to figure out what indices of that array represent the shaded region of that diagram you are showing. Clearly, the vertical index starts in the middle and goes to the end. The horizontal index varies depending upon the vertical index.

Comment: I don't understand these words as used in this question

Answer (score 1):

Well, I won't just do your homework but here is some code that you can consider a **hint** to get you started.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printRelevant(int n)
{
  for(int r=0; r<n; ++r)
    {
      for(int c=0; c<n; ++c)
        {
          if (r < n/2 || c > r || c < n-r-1)
            {
              printf("-");
            }
          else
            {
              printf("X");
            }
        }
      printf("\n");
    }
}


int main(void) {
  printRelevant(17);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-----------------
-----------------
-----------------
-----------------
-----------------
-----------------
-----------------
-----------------
--------X--------
-------XXX-------
------XXXXX------
-----XXXXXXX-----
----XXXXXXXXX----
---XXXXXXXXXXX---
--XXXXXXXXXXXXX--
-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```